# Me genera este error el seed "You requested 1 items but there are only 0 items in the collection"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de hacer un seed con Laravel 5.1 y el problema es que me genera los datos de la tabla users, pero de las otras 2 no lo hace. Mis codigos son los siguientes.

**ModelFactory**

```
$factory->define(Blog\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
    'tipoUsuario' => $faker->randomElement(['Administrador','Moderador','Invitado']),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
];
});

$factory->define(Blog\Articulo::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'titulo' => 'Probando el seeder y slug',
        'contenido' => $faker->paragraph,
         'foto' => 'http://programacion.net/files/article/20151030111039_laravel-logo-white.png',
         'etiqueta' => 'Laravel, Curso, Blog, Primero, 2016',
        'user_id' => \Blog\User::all()->random()->id,
        'categoria_id' => \Blog\Categoria::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});

$factory->define(Blog\Categoria::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
    '    nombre' => $faker->randomElement(['Html5','Html4.1','CSS','Laravel-5','Laravel-4','JavaScript']),
    ];
});
```

Y este es mi **DatabaseSeeder** desde aquí los llamo.

```
public function run()
{
    Model::unguard();

    //factory('Blog\User',50)->create();
    factory('Blog\Articulo',20)->create();
    factory('Blog\Categoria',5)->create();
    // $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

    Model::reguard();
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el "php artisan db:seed" o "php artisan migrate --seed"
Me genera ese error **You requested 1 items but there are only 0 items in the collection**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el factory de los artículos estás obteniendo un id aleatorio de Categoría que por lo visto no existe aún, teniendo en cuenta que el seeder de categorías se ejecuta después:

```
    // ...
    'categoria_id' => \Blog\Categoria::all()->random()->id,
    // ...
```

Se solucionaría cambiando el orden de ejecución de los seeders de categoría y artículo:

```
public function run()
{
    Model::unguard();

    factory('Blog\User',50)->create();
    factory('Blog\Categoria',5)->create();
    factory('Blog\Articulo',20)->create();
    // $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

    Model::reguard();
}
```

Comment: Gracias, shaz. Me sacas la pata del barro muchas veces jaja